# PHP: Can a function know if it's being assigned as a value?

Tags: php, function

In other words, can `fn()` know that it is being used as `$var = fn();` rather than as `fn();`?

A use case would be to `echo` the return value in the latter case but to `return` it in the former.

Can this be done without passing a parameter to the function to declare which way it is being used?

Comment: Do you know if you're in the matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many PHP functions do this by passing a boolean value called $return which returns the value if $return is true, or prints the value if $return is false. A couple of examples are [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) and [highlight_file()](http://php.net/highlight_file).

So your function would look like this:

```
function fn($return=false) {
    if ($return) {
        return 'blah';
    } else {
        echo 'blah';
    }
}
```

Any other way will not be good programming style.

Answer (score 3):

No, and it shouldn't. It's a pretty basic premise of the language that functions are unaware of the context in which they are used. This allows you to decompose your application, because each part (function) is completely isolated from its surroundings.

That said, what you can do about this particular use-case, is to tturn on output buffering. By default `echo` will send data to stdout, but you can set a buffer, which will capture the output into a variable instead. For example:

```
function foo() {
  echo "Hello World";
}
foo(); // will output "Hello World"
ob_start();
foo();
$foo = ob_get_clean(); // will assign the string "Hello World" into the variable $foo
```

In addition to that, it is generally considered bad style to have functions output directly. You should generally return a string and leave it for the top level of your script to output. Ideally there should be just one single echo statement in your entire application.

Answer (score 2):

Just think about how the interpreter executes this statement:

```
$var = fn();
```

The interpreter evaluates operands right-to-left with the assignment operator, so first it will evaluate the expression on the right hand side (`fn()` in this case) and will then assign the result to `$var`. Every expression returns a value, and it's your choice of what to do with this value.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to find it out. The unique thing you could do, is to grab the call stack (https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) and inspect it.

Comment: That's a pretty bad thing to do, unless it's for debugging.

Comment: Because it's a very magic and non-standard way to change the behaviour of a function. Besides, mocking with a stacktrace in production code, is asking for trouble. An errorhandler would qualify as "for debugging", in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be easily done but, so what if you just passed an extra boolean variable to the function? That way, the end of the function would look like:

```
if (namespace) {
    return $output;
} else {
    echo $output;
}
```

Seems a pretty simple workaround.

Comment: I specified in the question: "Can this be done without passing a parameter to the function to declare which way it is being used?"

Comment: Scanned the question quick and didn't see that. Edited to reflect.

Comment: The downside of passing a parameter is that it's more code, it's code that has to change everywhere it's used in order to change parameter length or order. More than that, I asked the question because I genuinely want to know more about PHP language/syntax features.

Comment: When you put it like that, it's something I'd like the answer to as well. I've always looked at that solution as the time-saving solution and, you're right, after a while, it starts to look like a scotch tape solution. If there's a better way, I'd love to hear about it.